# Is this a correct way of expressing number in natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, time-series

I want to express below number in $ e^x $ format,

$$ (1.05)^{1000} $$

so I used following Identity

$$ e^x = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^x $$

$$ = \left( \left(1 + \frac{1}{20} \right)^{20}\right)^{50} $$

$$ = e^{50} $$

is it correct or something I am doing wrong. please help me.

Comment: I think you mean *natural logarithm*.

Comment: yes, Natural logarithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get this identity from? The one that I know exists, looks like this:

$ lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x = e$

You want to find $x$ such that $e^x = (1.05)^{1000}$. We can take natural log on both sides and solve it like this,

$ \Rightarrow ln(e^x) = ln((1.05)^{1000}) \\ \Rightarrow x \cdot ln(e) = 1000 ln(1.05) \\ \Rightarrow x = 1000 \times 0.04879$

where $ln(1.05) = 0.04879$.

Comment: Thanks now it is clear for me

Comment: Don't you mean  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x = e$. Because $ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x = 1$